# Strange "ModuleNotFoundErrior no module named iexfinance"

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running this code in Pycharm community edition 2017.3.3, it works perfectly. However, when I try running it from the command line I get:

"From iexfinance import get_historical_data
ModuleNotFoundError no module named iexfinance"

Any ideas? as you can guess I'm REALLY!! new to Python.

```
<code>
from iexfinance import get_historical_data
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.annotations import Title
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from datetime import date
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
import time
from math import pi
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
#This works in pycharm community but not from Command Line
ticker=input("Ticker: ")
start_date=input("Start Date: ")
end_date = input("End Date: ")
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
#Get rid of nsepy will use Quandl instead
df = get_historical_data(ticker, start=start_date, end=end_date, output_format='pandas')
#Show it
print(df)
kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = [1],
                  observation_matrices = [1],
                  initial_state_mean = df['close'].values[0],
                  initial_state_covariance = 1,
                  observation_covariance=1,
                  transition_covariance=.01)
state_means,_ = kf.filter(df[['close']].values)
state_means = state_means.flatten()
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
mids = (df.open + df.close)/2
spans = abs(df.close-df.open)
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, toolbar_location="left",y_axis_label = "Price",
           x_axis_label = "Date")
p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.rect(df.date[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color='green', line_color="green")
p.rect(df.date[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color='red', line_color="red")
p.line(df.date,state_means,line_width=1,line_color = 'blue',legend="Kalman filter")
t = Title()
t.text = 'Kalman Filter Estimation'
p.title = t
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
#Needed this
output_file(ticker + ".html")
show(p)

</code>
```

Comment: Hum... did you install the package `iexfinance` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with easy_install, it installed it, but still getting same error. Outside of IDE. I'm thinking this is related to the version  maybe I have Python 2.7 and 3.6? going to try getting rid of one...

Comment: What does the command line give you back if you run `pip install iexfinance`?

Answer (score 2):

The package has been updated. Import the function as follows:

```
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
```

I found it in the [usage examples](https://addisonlynch.github.io/iexfinance/stable/usage.html?highlight=get_historical_data#historical-data) of the [`iexfinance` documentation](https://addisonlynch.github.io/iexfinance/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install that package. You can use ‘pip install iexfinance’